# Facebook's 360-degree "Soround 360" technology for VR headsets

Tags: facebook, video, video-streaming, gear-vr, 360-virtual-reality

Facebook released a demo video of their Surround 360 technology a few days ago, called "Here and Now": https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10154659446236729/ 
Apparently they are using their proposed cubic mapping perspective for this. Can someone familiar verify that?

When on my Gear VR and I rotate my head, I notice a slight quality improvement. So also, does anybody know if they are using an adaptive view-aware streaming such as DASH or something for that (which will be impressive)? I am assuming it is not first downloaded and played, so maybe this is not due to the rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uses pyramid encoding. They put a sphere inside a pyramid so that the base of the pyramid is the full-resolution FOV and the sides of the pyramid gradually decrease in quality until they reach a point directly opposite from the viewport, behind the viewer. That explains why, when you turned your head with the GearVR on, you noticed a quality change. They don't use MPEG-DASH, yet.

https://code.facebook.com/posts/1126354007399553/next-generation-video-encoding-techniques-for-360-video-and-vr/

Comment: Thanks. So for what does it mean of what you said "gradually decrease in quality"? One the same page they say "...[we] implement view-dependent adaptive bit rate streaming for playback".

Comment: Also here they say they use dynamic streaming?! https://code.facebook.com/posts/194023157622878/gear-vr-to-get-dynamic-streaming-for-360-video/

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself wrong. When I said they don't use dynamic streaming, I meant that they don't use MPEG-DASH, yet. They use view-dependent bit rate adaptation but still no user's bandwidth detection like traditional DASH implementations. Nokia, Samsung and QUALCOMM advocating for [a standard way](http://blog.harmonicinc.com/the-vr-360-ecosystem-is-starting-to-take-shape/) to deliver VR video over DASH, so sooner or later we'll start to see big companies adopting DASH solutions for VR, all on the same direction. I've updated my answer, please mark it as correct if you think so now.

Comment: Tnx. It's interesting they have not yet implemented DASH for that.